# Kill a nonresponsive window?

Tags: 14.04, process, gnome-classic

In Gnome Classic in 14.04, I am running a program (it opens a chm file, but I forgot the name of the program and the window doesn't show the name of the porgram) in a window. It becomes non responsive, and even right clicking it and choosing close don't close it.

How can I find out its pid, and kill it from gnome terminal? Thanks.

Comment: and http://askubuntu.com/q/104903/158442

Comment: and:http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes - it is `xkill` that helps in those single-windows cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `xkill`.

You may run it from a terminal window or from the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> Unity HUD.

It will transform your mouse cursor into an **×** and whatever window you click next with the <kbd>LEFT mouse button (1)</kbd> will be killed. You abort this by clicking anywhere with the <kbd>RIGHT mouse button (2)</kbd>.

Comment: I believe, it's not pre-installed. The package is `x11-utils` ;)

Comment: Thanks. I have to use keyboard to switch between programs' windows after running xkill in terminal.

Comment: @Tim Yes, that's of course true. If the window you need to kill is completely covered by another, you may not use the mouse to move or minimize it while you're running `xkill`. You either have to navigate between the windows using your keyboard (e.g. `Alt`+`Tab`) or arrange your windows in a good way before typing `xkill`.

Comment: I accidentally close the panel for showing time etc, while under xkill. Is there some way to reopen the panel?

Comment: @Tim I think you could try to restart Unity. look at my question here: http://askubuntu.com/q/681176/367990

Comment: it is gnome classic

Comment: @Tim Then you probably need to find a way to restart gnome classic. Easiest way will be to log out and back in.