# Why do I have to restart my computer to see installed programs?

Tags: software-installation, restart

I just installed Ubuntu this morning and I installed a few programs like Chrome and Atom but after I installed them I couldnt find them using the search. I thought I'd restart my computer and when I did, I found them both. I brushed it off and thought maybe it's because I just installed Ubuntu and it needed a restart or something, but then I installed another program through the terminal and the exact same thing happened again.

Comment: I am not sure why the shortcuts for some programs don't show up in the dash immediately but see http://askubuntu.com/q/681176/15003 to see how you can refresh the dash unity without rebooting.

Comment: This happens to me as well, but I find that after a while it finds them. So I'm thinking the apps menu only refresh every x minutes. Running the app manually sometimes makes it shown up right away.

Comment: @dorian I just opened it manually and I still cant see it in the search. I also tried the command in the link posted by edwinksl and that doesn't work either.

Comment: I wonder if those programs get installed in /opt, cause Dash doesn't look in /opt. You could try `/usr/bin/updatedb` instead of restart.

Comment: I just remember it coming up eventually. Because of this and other issues, and overheating, I switched to Gnome so I can't try anything on my end, that's just what I remembered. I like unity, but the problems weren't worth it.