# Upgraded Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10, and Unity graphical elements not showing up

Tags: unity, upgrade, 15.04

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 from 15.04.

#### Problems:

- The Unity sidebar and top bar are nowhere to be found.
  No matter if I push the cursor against the screen border.

  - The Unity top bar only appears when logging in. Fully interactive, functionality intact.
  - The Unity side bar is nowhere to be found. I never see it.
- Another notable missing feature is ES-EN keyboard switching with `Super+Space`. I assume since it's part of the top bar.

Every other program seems to be working properly.

Also, I have the Variety wallpaper changer installed (still works), and think it could be a possible culprit.

---

#### I have tried:

- Restarting.
- Restarting Unity as shown in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/496001/467883).
- Opening up the `unity-tweak-tool` and resetting all tabs to normal. *I had a retractable/hidden side bar before the upgrade*, but toggling this feature doesn't help.
- Running `sudo apt-get upgrade` in case any packages were missing, to no avail.

I've managed to get by with `Ctrl+Alt+T` for opening up the terminal and `Alt+Tab` to change between opened program windows, but it's fairly uncomfortable.

Any ideas or assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to restart unity with the terminal?

Comment: Yes. Updated description to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I had the same problem you can install the compiz-config-manager from terminal and then just tick the unity box and enable unity from there

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Comment: Installed as you said, but I'm unclear on how to start up the manager. Typing `compizconfig-settings-manager` brings up nothing...

Comment: @JoseHdez type ccsm to start it

Comment: Thanks! That solved it. Apparently there were conflicting key bindings and that disabled the Unity plugin. I'd upvote but my rep is too low ;p

Comment: Glad I could help