# Ubuntu 16:04: Launcher and top menu bar freezes after screen lock

Tags: 16.04, launcher, freeze

Ubuntu novice here. :)

So far very happy and pleased with Ubuntu, but have a strange issue. I have re-installed Ubuntu 16.04 from scratch two times now, but problem keeps recurring:

When my computer has been in screenlock I can log in and active windows can be used with both mouse and keyboard but the Launcher and the top menu bar are both non-responding. Using Alt+F2 works, etc, but I cannot press or start any programs on the Launcher and also no reactions from pressing anything in the top menu bar.

A restart/reboot immediately solves the problem every time but is of course very inconvenient.

Below are some details for my system. I would appreciate any input or suggestions. :)

```
g@NUC1 ~ $ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.4.0-36-generic (buildd@lcy01-01) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) ) #55-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 18:01:55 UTC 2016
```

```
g@NUC1 ~ $ sudo lshw -short
H/W path         Device     Class          Description
======================================================
                            system         Desktop Computer
/0                          bus            NUC6i5SYB
/0/0                        memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/22                       memory         64KiB L1 cache
/0/23                       memory         64KiB L1 cache
/0/24                       memory         512KiB L2 cache
/0/25                       memory         4MiB L3 cache
/0/26                       processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6260U CPU @ 1.80
/0/27                       memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/27/0                     memory         8GiB SODIMM Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5
/0/27/1                     memory         8GiB SODIMM Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5
/0/100                      bridge         Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
/0/100/2                    display        Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
/0/100/14                   bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/14/0      usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/2               bus            USB hub
/0/100/14/1      usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1/1               input          Dell USB Keyboard
/0/100/14/1/2               bus            USB hub
/0/100/14/1/2/2             input          EIZO USB HID Monitor
/0/100/14/1/3               input          Optical USB Mouse
/0/100/14/1/7               communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/14.2                 generic        Intel Corporation
/0/100/16                   communication  Intel Corporation
/0/100/17                   storage        Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c                   bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c/0      wlp1s0     network        Wireless 8260
/0/100/1e                   generic        Intel Corporation
/0/100/1e.6                 generic        Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f                   bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.2                 memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3                 multimedia     Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.4                 bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.6      eno1       network        Ethernet Connection I219-V
/0/1             scsi0      storage        
/0/1/0.0.0       /dev/sda   disk           240GB INTEL SSDSC2BW24
/0/1/0.0.0/1                volume         236MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2     /dev/sda2  volume         215GiB EXT4 volume
/0/1/0.0.0/3     /dev/sda3  volume         8398MiB Linux swap volume
/0/2             scsi2      storage        
/0/2/0.0.0       /dev/sdb   disk           256GB SanDisk SD8SNAT2
/0/2/0.0.0/1     /dev/sdb1  volume         238GiB EXT4 volume
```

```
g@NUC1 ~ $ df -h
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                    7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   1.6G  9.5M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda2               212G  4.8G  197G   3% /
tmpfs                   7.7G   16M  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                   7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1               234M  3.6M  230M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb1               235G  2.4G  221G   2% /home
tmpfs                   1.6G   76K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/home/g/.Private        235G  2.4G  221G   2% /home/g
```

```
g@NUC1 ~ $ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15749         911       13671         336        1166       14182
Swap:          8398           0        8398
```

Comment: Something similar happens to me - the mouse also sometimes clicks into the wrong window, despite the cursor being in the right location. I've found that a log out also fixes the glitch.

Answer (score 0):

I find that restarting unity from a terminal usually fixes things, but often many of my applications will have shut down.

Comment: How to restart unity: https://askubuntu.com/a/496001/149571